# Showing that a function that rearranges the decimal representation is continuos.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

So I got this one exercise, and I just want to ask if my conjecture and my idea of proving it is correct, I won't be too much rigorous.

Here's the exercise:

> Let $(q_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in (\mathbb{N}^*) ^{ \mathbb{N}}$ such that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, q_{n+1}> q_{n}$ . If $0,a_1a_2a_3 \cdot \cdot \cdot$ is the decimal representation of $x \in [0,1)$, we denote $f(x) = 0,a_{q_1}a_{q_2} \cdot \cdot \cdot$. Study the continuity of $f$ at the right and at the left.

Now, my idea was if $x=a_1a_2...$ then let's put $$x'= \begin{bmatrix}
a_1\\ 
a_2\\ 
a_3\\ 
.
\end{bmatrix}$$
Thus $$f(x') = \begin{bmatrix}
a_{q_1}\\ 
a_{q_2}\\ 
a_{q_3}\\ 
.
\end{bmatrix}$$

Now to study the continuity at right at $x$ for example, I would need to show that for an $\epsilon >0$, $\exists \delta$ such that $0< x_0 -x < \delta$ we have $|f(x) - f(x_0)| < \epsilon$. For this, I thought of using the $|| \cdot || _{\infty}$ norm. Thus I define $x_0 = b_1b_2b_3 ...$ and thus $f(x_0) = b_{q_1}b_{q_2}b_{q_3}...$. And then we have:
$$||f(x')-f(x_0')||_{\infty} = \underset{i \in \mathbb{N}}{sup} \{ |a_{q_{i}} - b_{q_i}| \} $$
Which in turn:
$$ \underset{i \in \mathbb{N}}{sup} \{ |a_{q_{i}} - b_{q_i}| \} \leq
\underset{i \in \mathbb{N}}{sup} \{ |a_{i} - b_{i}| \} $$
So suffices to take $\delta = \epsilon$.
Would my idea be feasible? Do I have the right to express an integer in the form of a vector?

Comment: Sure but, the norm shall decrease as we go deep into the decimals.

Comment: @hyprfrcb I don't really understand you. You say "sure" and then proceed to state that the function isn't continuous. And from your example, I can see that what I proved is essentially wrong.

Comment: Note that the function is not continuous, given f(x)=[1 3 5...], x=0.909090... maps into 0.000... and x=0.009090 maps into 0.000... too

Comment: I mean that you can represent the numbers and function as a vector of infinite dimension, despite of the continuity of the function.

Comment: @hyprfrcb It just seems to me that the closer $x_0$ gets to $x$, the number of first $n$ terms in both vectors that are identical will get bigger.

Comment: If the sequence $f$ must be ordered, it would neccesarily omit digits, if not, this is just the natural line. Unless the problem is missing some syntaxis.... For example if $q=[1 3 5...]$, the function would be $f(x)=0.a_1a_3a_5...$ and thus the given counterexample would hold.

Comment: @hyprfrcb Not sure what you mean by ordered, but yes, it would necessarily omit digits. But keep in mind, whatever $x$ we take, the sequence $(q_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I assume that one always chooses the decimal expansion that does not end with an infinite sequence of $9$'s)

HINT: The function is continuous on the right but not continuous on the left.

To see that $f$ is not continuous, say $q_1 > 1$. Consider $x= 0.1000\ldots = \frac{1}{10}$. Let now the sequence $x_n = \frac{1}{10} - \frac{1}{10^n} \to \frac{1}{10}$. We see that $f(x_n) \to 1$, but $f(\frac{1}{10}) = 0$.

To see the continuity on the right, notice that if $x_n \to x$, $x_n > x\in [0,1)$, then the decimal expansions of $x_n$ converge to the decimal expansion of $x$. ( they coincide on larger and larger parts).